# Twilio android sdk crashes on conference call

Tags: android, twilio, voip

I am using the twilio android sdk for conference call but when I use the function `device.connect(foo)` to create the connection to the conference, my app crashes.

My code :

```
public void connectToConference(String name){

    updateAudioRoute(true);
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

    parameters.put("To","conference:"+BaseActivity.currentUser.getFirstName()+BaseActivity.currentUser.getLastName());
    if(device != null){
             connection = device.connect(parameters, null);
    }

    if (connection == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create new connection");
    }
}
```

The error :

> art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: 
>   JNI
>   FindClass called with pending exception 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError'
>   thrown in void
>
> > com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.Call.makeCall(com.twilio.client.impl.session.Account,
> >     java.lang.String, com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.MessageData):-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the issue.

The problem was JNI with device.connect() of library

> 1.2.7

The exception was not catch.

I changed the library, I use

> 1.2.8

and my problem was resolve.

Comment: Hi @Malcom i also want to make such app . can you please guide me how to use twilio sdk for making confernce call ?

Comment: I am so sorry to answer now but I changed project and I was not available while this new project ! I hope that you could install the lTwilio SDK library

Comment: No Problem @Malcom i have made my app hopoefully will upload on store in a month